# Max number of spies

Tags: civilization-5

Say one civ hits renaissance when I am still medieval. I get an extra spy when I hit renaissance as well? So 6 from era + 1 from wonder + 1 if england for 8 total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only 7 I believe.

- You get a spy when someone hits Renaissance, and +1 spy every time
  you advance an era beyond Renaissance.
- England gets +1 spy.
- Building a National Intelligence Agency will give +1 spy.

http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Espionage_%28Civ5%29